# My Laravel + Vue + Inertia Js form submits on some devices and doesnt on some

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

`I rolled out my laravel site to users, and they have to fill in a form to register themselves, when some people fill in the form it works, whne others do it doesnt work, and sometimes i also get a 302 error not sure what i'm doing wrong

```
public function store(Request $request){
   $request->validate([
        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'phone_number' => 'required|regex:/^[0-9]{11}$/',
        'constituency' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'bacenta' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'picture' => 'required|file|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048', // Assuming it's an image upload

    ]);

    // Create a new member instance
    $member = new Members();
    $member->first_name = $request->input('first_name');
    $member->last_name = $request->input('last_name');
    $member->phone_number = $request->input('phone_number');
    $member->bacenta_id = $request->input('bacenta');

    // Handle the uploaded image
    if ($request->hasFile('picture')) {
        $image = $request->file('picture');
        $imageName = $request->input('first_name').'.'. $request->input('last_name').'.'.time() . '.' . $image->extension();
        Storage::putFileAs('public/images/', $image, $imageName);
        $member->picture = $imageName;
    }

    // Save the member to the database
    $member->save();

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Member created successfully']);

}
```

i tried to

add csrf
make sure the request is being sent
no redirects`

Comment: It would help if there is a specific error. Try adding a `try/catch` block on your method to see what error it is.